# $H_1(U)=\mathbb{Z}^n$ if $U$ is complement of $n$ distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: homology-cohomology

Let $U$ be the complement of $n$ distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ How can we show that $H_1(U)=\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

$U$ retracts to  a bouquet of $n$ circles whose fundamental group is a free group of $n$ generators so after abelianisation you get $Z^n$.